# Rails 3 asset dir accessible from CNAME root and app subdirectory simultaneously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I have a rails 3.0.10 application that I have available within an application directory, like this:

```
https://apps.example.com/myRails3App
```

The server is RHEL 5 using passenger. Out of the box the application works great and I did not have to wrap my routes in a scope.

Then I set up a CNAME alias from a new domain to point at the application, like this:

```
http://great.vanityurl.com
```

Now, after redeploying the application and restarting the server, when I visit the application from apps.example.com/myRails3App all of my assets called from "stylesheet_link_tag" (or "javascript_include_tag") are looking for the assets at "apps.example.com/stylesheets" instead of the correct "apps.example.com/myRails3App/stylesheets" (though standard link tags are working correctly).

Meanwhile the application looks great from the vanityurl, since the reference to great.vanityurl.com/stylesheets resolves correctly.

It would seem that I should use something like Rails' "relative_url_root' but this is of course not available in rails 3.0.10 (as far as I am able to understand).

What should I do to make sure that the application looks and functions identically whether it is visited via the original location (apps.example.com/myRails3App) or the vanity url (great.vanityurl.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winfield's answer would work for Rails 3.1, but 3.0 doesn't like 'config.assets.prefix='.

Thankfully, while it wasn't the final solution, he pointed me in the right direction with 'config.action_controller.asset_host=". After checking the Rails 3.0 api for asset_host=, I discovered asset_path=.

I ended up putting this in my application.rb:

```
config.action_controller.asset_path = proc { |asset_path|
      if (Rails.env != "development_local") and (!asset_path.starts_with?("/myRails3App"))
        "/myRails3App#{asset_path}"
      else
        asset_path
      end
    }
```

And during deployment I have my capistrano script generate a symlink from {app_root}/public  to {app_root}/public/myRails3App, allowing all asset calls to myRails3App/stylesheets, for instance, to work whether or not the user is visiting from a URL in which the application directory is required.

This solution feels dirty, but it works.

Thanks, Winfield, for helping me get my application to be functional.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your immediate problem using a combination of:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'apps.example.com'
config.assets.prefix = "/myRails3App"
```

To directly control the URLs generated from the Rails asset helpers you're mentioning.